# Text data in form-field too long

Tags: mysql, forms, text, nginx

I have a form with a text area field. I put some text information there and send it as post request. This information is about 2M of text. Everything goes fine with server and database because post request sends this amount of data to server and mysql saves it correctly in DB. Problem is that after that I just can't render text data back into form on edit-page. Page loads only half and stops loading on that text_area. What can cause this problem? Can anyone suggest me smthing? Thanks in advance.

P.S: After deleting some amount of text from text-area and update item, it renders it properly to form on edit-page. This is sure because of amount of data but is it server or db or whatever I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed. problem was in javascript rendering fckeditor

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers impose some limits on the amount of data that can be entered in a textarea. Limits like 32 or 64 kilobytes  (32,768 or 65,536 characters) have been observed. Such limits, if they exist, are caused by simplistic implementations, and they are independent of the values of the rows and cols attributes.

Such limitations cannot be taken as solutions to the problem of limiting textarea input size. They are just browser-specific limitations (which shouldn't really exist, and will hopefully be removed in new versions). Instead, they constitute a problem.

It is unlikely that a user takes the trouble of typing more than 32,768 characters into a textarea when filling out a form. Browsers' user interfaces for such purposes are generally very poor, with extremely limited editing capabilities. But a user might cut and paste some long text which he has typed using an editor or a text processing program.

If you expect that some users might wish to include very long texts when filling out a form of yours, consider making it possible to use alternative methods of data submission. Depending on the case, this might mean one or more of the following:

Comment: forgot to say that this only happens on the server side, on localhost testing server everything goes fine (slow but fine).

Comment: so this ain't browser probler for sure